# RoboEarth - Distance of Detected Object

Tags: ros, kinect, pose, pcl, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am trying to use RoboEarth to detect some objects. Once I've detected the object I wanted to know the distance to this object but am unsure how to obtain this information. Does anyone know how I can do this? The [tutorial page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth/Tutorials/Using%20recorded%20models%20for%20object%20detection) for detecting objects says: "Also, a new tf transformation is published that specifies the objects estimated position." so I am assuming it is possible to get the distance?

Running rostopic list at runtime will give:

```
/camera/depth/camera_info
/camera/depth/disparity
/camera/depth/image
/camera/depth/image_raw
/camera/depth/image_rect
/camera/depth/image_rect_raw
/camera/depth/points
/camera/depth/rectify_depth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/rectify_depth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/camera_info
/camera/depth_registered/disparity
/camera/depth_registered/image
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw
/camera/depth_registered/points
/camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth/parameter_updates
/camera/driver/parameter_descriptions
/camera/driver/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/camera_info
/camera/ir/image_raw
/camera/ir/image_rect
/camera/ir/rectify_ir/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/rectify_ir/parameter_updates
/camera/projector/camera_info
/camera/rgb/camera_info
/camera/rgb/debayer/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/debayer/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_color
/camera/rgb/image_mono
/camera/rgb/image_raw
/camera/rgb/image_rect
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color
/camera/rgb/rectify_color/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/rectify_color/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/rectify_mono/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/rectify_mono/parameter_updates
/re_kinect/detection_results
/re_kinect/feature_pcl
/re_kinect/model_path
/re_vslam/new_model
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank You

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34906/roboearth---distance-of-detected-object/) by [AksatShah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1704/aksatshah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2012-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The detected pose of the object is published as a tf transformation named "OBJECTCLASS.OBJECTNAME", as written on [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/re_kinect_object_detector#Provided_tf_Transforms).

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AksatShah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1704/aksatshah/) on 2012-06-07**:
Thanks ddimarco. In the end I just wrote a subscriber which subscribed to the re_kinect/detection_results topic and filtered out only the points3d data..Then by getting the max and min values of each x,y,z I could get the box around the object. Thank you for the help!!

**Comment by [AksatShah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1704/aksatshah/) on 2012-06-07**:
Thanks ddimarco

**Comment by [AksatShah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1704/aksatshah/) on 2012-06-07**:
Thanks ddimarco